# Why does my div not expand to the size of the content

Tags: css

I'm pretty sure that I'm supposed to use a clearfix or something to remedy this, but I have been fighting with this layout for too long and I'm going cross-eyed from the code so bear with me.

My [example](http://newads.socialhippo.com/en/product.asp?page=N-12_ST_IB_%28soiltight%29_Pipe) shows what happens when the far right column (`#rightbox`) has too much information and it breaks out of the main wrapper (`#interior_wrap`).

Because `#rightbox` is floated, I'm sure that's what's causing it, but I think I'm too close to see the solution so any help would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ah, the most asked css question on SO..

```
#container { overflow:hidden; zoom:1; }
```

or `#container:after { content:""; clear:both; display:block; }` if you get clipping.

PS - do not use position:absolute to center things, use `margin:0 auto`

Comment: Is #container the example that I apply to my #interior_wrap?

Comment: Yes, it is. And don't set explicit heights anywhere or you'll experience oddities.

Comment: Try the clearfix `after` method I supplied instead. Your css messes the overflow hidden fix up.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I've adjusted it correctly, but that didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: It would be useful if you told me what you modified.

Comment: Sorry, I changed my #interior_wrap to this:
#interior_wrap {
margin:0 auto;
width:920px;
background:#FFFFFF;
background-image: url(/images/interior_back.gif);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
border: 3px solid #000;
left: 50%;
z-index: 10;
}
#interior_wrap:after { content:""; clear:both; display:block; }

Comment: Your floats are children of the wrap_bkgrnd thing. So apply it to that.

Comment: Ok, so I changed it to: #interior_wrap_bkgnd:after { content:""; clear:both; display:block; } but that didn't do it either, do I need to apply the "margin:0 auto" to #interior_wrap_bkgnd as well?

Comment: Ok, just try the `overflow:hidden;` then.

Comment: Now it doesn't run outside of #interior_wrap_bkgnd but the content from #rightbox still runs over the footer. If I change the overflow to visible, will that let me see all the content then?

Comment: You need to refactor this entire layout. You are using position relative with top/bottom values, that is not the ideal way. Remove top:125px from rightbox. It causes it to move 125px from the top, so it goes 125px into the footer...

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example that explains the theory

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/19/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/

Comment: I'm definitely going to read this, I've always given up because I keep having this error, but now I have to learn it.